# HAProxy not forwarding requests to backend server

Tags: haproxy

I have HAProxy (v1.5.8) as a load balancer with keepalived (v1.2.2) to maintain high availability. I also have several Jetty servers on a different machine on the local network as backend server with a webapp.

The problem I have is: I can access to the web app through it IP (z.z.z.z in the code below), but when I try to access by the VIP(y.y.y.y in the code below) I get a connection refused error. I dont have any iptables rule set (Debian 7).

My haproxy.cfg file is this one:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    #stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    #stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen stats x.x.x.x:9000
    mode http
    balance
    option httplog
    timeout client 5000
    timeout connect 4000
    timeout server 30000
    stats uri /haproxy_stats
    stats realm HAProxy/Statistics
    stats auth user:passwd
    stats admin if TRUE

listen webfarm y.y.y.y:8080
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats auth someuser:somepassword
   balance roundrobin
   cookie JSESSIONID prefix
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor
   option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    server webA z.z.z.z:9400 check
```

In the keepalived conf file I have defined the VIP I will use (Is the same one defined in the haproxy.cfg :

```
 virtual_ipaddress {
            y.y.y.y
 }
```

In the stats web I get the next results:

[HAProxy Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnXDZ.jpg)

After this, I believe that haproxy cannot get to the backends as they are displayed as frontend servers. I am missing something in the conf files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, 'frontend' and 'backend' are summary lines not titles. It is normal for the servers to be between the two.

Your backend is down because it is returning a 404 to haproxy. You need to make /check.txt return a valid response.

Comment: I've managed to get the server to return a valid response using an apache test server, but the redirection still fails.
If i go to the apache ip I can get the index file ok, but if I go to the virtual IP haproxy is listening I get the Host Unreachable error.

A `ip addr sh eth0` tells me that the IP is working. Do you know why it might be failing to redirect the requests?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simply disabling your checks until you get a bit more comfortable with HAProxy as a whole. Id also recommend you turn on the stats page, which will give you a better visualization of what HAProxy sees. See below:

```
    ###########################################
    #
    # HAProxy Stats page
    #
    ###########################################

    listen stats
      bind *:9090
      mode  http
      maxconn  10
      stats  enable
      stats  hide-version
      stats  realm Haproxy\ Statistics
      stats  uri /
      stats  auth -----:-----
```

Comment: Just saw that you had stats page listed, didnt see that before.